# SSRS 2012 - Hide unused columns at a page level

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, service, reporting

I am trying to create a report in SSRS 2012 which page breaks on a given group's change (that part works fine), but also only shows the columns relevant to each particular page.

I have tried various forms of Expressions like the one below on the Column Visibility option to no avail

```
=IIF(Max(Field, Dataset)= "",TRUE,FALSE)
```

For a quick mock up, say that I have a City group, a Store child group, and a ProductsCarried yes/no (or 1/0) value.  My desire for this exercise it to have one city per page with all of the stores in that city, then a cross tab that **only** only shows the products that a given city sells.

```
City       Store       Lawn Chairs   Tables   BBQ Grills
Boston     Store #1         X          X
           Store #2                    X          X

---  PAGE BREAK ---
City       Store       Mowers   Shovels 
Dallas     Store #7      X         
           Store #8      X         X
```

Instead, what I'm getting is something more along the lines of this

```
City       Store       Lawn Chairs   Tables   BBQ Grills   Mowers    Shovels
Boston     Store #1         X          X
           Store #2                    X          X

---  PAGE BREAK ---
City       Store       Lawn Chairs   Tables   BBQ Grills   Mowers    Shovels
Dallas     Store #7                                          X
           Store #8                                          X          X
```

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have one opr two column groups on item type?

Comment: You would have to break the report into multiple row groups with different columns or multiple tables. Column groups will repeat all distinct values, regardless of if the values match with a record in a row group. You can't optionally hide columns when columns are stretching out like that. However, you can only show columns that are defined in a group but when you add other groups then the columns from the new group will also be added.

Comment: Hi Ross, I have tried with just the "ProductsCarried" grouped as a column group and also (semi-randomly, hail-mary longshot) tried adding a City parent column group to ProductsCarried...  That was with having City still being a parent on the row groups too though...  Thinking about it, I didn't try with it solely as a parent column group.  I had exhausted all logical (to me) options at that point and was trying anything.

Comment: Thx!  Our replies crossed paths above.  Could you possibly elaborate a tad on "You would have to break the report into multiple row groups with different columns or multiple tables."?  At one point I did try a table within a table, but I didn't make much headway with that.

Comment: I want to say there is a level at which you can't exclude columns with matching data inside and below the scope. I am not sure if it is a Row Group or a Table/Matrix. The more I think about it the more I am leaning towards Table. If you think about it a bit, I would be very complicated to have column offsets within a ssrs row group. Perhaps each group has it's table or better yet, a table grouped on category with sub tables withing each group, maybe there column offsets would be allowed. My two cents.

Comment: Thank you Ross, I will play around with that.  Yes though, it does make sense that this is probably asking too much of the SSRS engine.  It seemed simple in my head.  :)